# 100(net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED): connection closed unexpectedlyI g

Tags: php, apache

I get that error from chrome (all the other browsers appear blank), the problem is that, I cant see the error.. I have got a lot of code on my page, and I dont seem to find what caused the error.. could you help me?!?! cause i dont know why it is caused

I get it from my php code and i am using dreamweaver.

This is how my connection is defined:

```
   <?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_QASite = "localhost";
$database_QASite = "qasite";
$username_QASite = "root";
$password_QASite = "";
$QASite = mysql_connect($hostname_QASite, $username_QASite, $password_QASite) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>

    if ((isset($_POST['topic_id'])) && ($_POST['topic_id'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM topic WHERE topic_id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['topic_id'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_QASite, $QASite);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $QASite) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

some of the other php code:

```
if ((isset($_POST['sub_topic_id'])) && ($_POST['sub_topic_id'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM sub_topic WHERE sub_topic_id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['sub_topic_id'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_QASite, $QASite);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $QASite) or die(mysql_error());

  $deleteGoTo = "/QASite/Admin/main.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
 // header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_QASite, $QASite) or die(mysql_error());

// FUNCTIONS THAT INSERT AND MODIFY THE TOPICS
if(isset($_POST['update_topic']))
{
    UpdateTopic();
}
else if(isset($_POST['insert_topic_submit']))
{
   InsertSubTopic();
}
else if(isset($_POST['update_sub_topic']))
{

    UpdateSubTopic();
}
else if(isset($_POST['insert_topic']))
{
    InsertTopic();
}
```

Comment: That error indicates that something went wrong at a pretty fundamental level in the web server, PHP, or possibly both. The response process/thread in the web server died before sending even the response headers. A common cause of this is infinite loops segfaulting - run your script from the command line to see if you get any output at all. If you try to use an incorrectly compiled extension it may also cause this. Try `echo`ing data every so often and see how far you get before the error. You may find that nothing is logged by the web server application, check your OS' syslog.

Comment: nice answer..but why did people downvote my answer/?!!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure PHP is configured to display errors. Also, check the PHP error log.

Comment: how can I make sure it does that??

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
display_errors("1");`

should do it.